# Cannot recreate environment on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, urllib, urllib3

Despite numerous pip freezes and attempts, I cannot seem to get the same version of urllib on heroku as my development environment. My requirements are upto date and code runs fine on my development machine, but I cannot get past the error on the production environment which must be down to the version of urllib.

```
from urlparse import quote_plus
2015-11-05T08:24:38.133387+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: cannot import name quote_plus
```

Despite me trying the following import:

```
try:
    from urllib.parse import quote_plus
except ImportError:
    from urlparse import quote_plus
```

and my `requirements.txt`:

```
blinker==1.4
bson==0.4.1
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
flask-mongoengine==0.7.1
Flask-PyMongo==0.3.1
Flask-Sendmail==0.1
Flask-WTF==0.12
gunicorn==19.3.0
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.8
MarkupSafe==0.23
mongoengine==0.10.0
pymongo==2.9
pytz==2015.7
requests==2.8.1
six==1.10.0
urllib3==1.12
Wand==0.4.1
Werkzeug==0.10.4
WTForms==2.0.2
```

Comment: Which version of the python is used on heroku and on your development environment? It could be, that some of the libraries, that youve set in the requirements.txt doesn't support python 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with urllib3. The function you are trying to import is part of the standard library.

However, it is in a different place in Python 2 and 3, which is what your try/except is supposed to deal with. But you have the wrong location for Python 2: it is in [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus), not `urlparse`.

Really, though, you should try and run the same version of Python in both environments. Make sure you tell Heroku to use Python 3 by specifying it in a [runtime.txt](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes) file.

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful to use runtime.txt to select the actual version of python. Less of a headache.